# Font color in :content prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I've got this line of code:

```
{:content => product.description.capitalize, :inline_format => true}
```

I would like to change the font color. I've tried:

```
{:content => product.description.capitalize, :color => :red, :inline_format => true}
```

and:

```
{:content => product.description.capitalize, :font_color => :red, :inline_format => true}
```

But these don't work. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Try with 'text_color' ,

```
{:content => product.description.capitalize, :text_color => "#ff0000", :inline_format => true}
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it. I used tag <color rgb='009ddf'>

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is inside the comment from Jakub!

use  `:inline_format => true` to allow the use of `<color rgb='009ddf'> ... </color>` inside the text. Together with `<b>...</b>` for bold and `<u>...</u>`, for underline `<i>..</i>` for italic you can format the text inline.